# ng-grid enable/disable button in each row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angular ng-grid. The last column in grid is a button. The second last column is a dropdown list. I need to enable corresponding button when the user changes the dropdown value.

I tried following

ng-grid button column

```
cellTemplate: '<button ng-disabled="!disabled{{ scheduleList[ row.rowIndex ].job_id}}"  >Save</button>'
```

called update function when the dropdown is changed

```
  $scope.update = function() {
  $scope.disabled1 = true;
};
```

just for a testing purpose I have added `scheduleList[ row.rowIndex ].job_id = 1`

`$scope.disabled1 = true` should enable the button

code on dropdown

```
<select ng-change="update()" >
</select>
```

I mean If I hard code `ng-disabled="!disabled1`. This code is working fine.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: your `$scope.update` function is not accepting any parameter.

Comment: @dcodesmith I was just test if $scope.disabled1 = true, will enable the button. if ng-disabled="!disabled1"

Comment: Ermm ok. So what is the question here exactly. Sorry, I'm confused. @rajmohan

Comment: actually I have a dropdown. when it is changed I need to enable the correspoding button in that row. @dcodesmith

Comment: suggest you create a demo in plunker, and provide more detail as to what problem is

Comment: @charlietfl hmm...I will try that. can you just give me an idea how this can be implemented. Is there any other way with ng-grid

Comment: @dcodesmith  I think here the main issue is ng-disabled="disabled1" . if I hard code like this...it is working but when I use something like above code ...it is not working.

Comment: we don't know what your data looks like, or table config or why you even have a problem....create demo that replicates problem. WHen comments get this long and people keep asking what issue is...should be a clue you haven't properly set up the question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this instead:

```
$scope.update = function() {
  $scope.disabled = {};
  $scope.disabled[1] = true;
}
```

And then, on your cell template:

```
cellTemplate: '<button ng-disabled="!disabled[scheduleList[ row.rowIndex ].job_id]"  >Save</button>'
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8lft75